# This 2 image how can I change my WordPress left image (edit page) like the right image please

Tags: wordpress

## ![enter image description here](https:[image]//i.stack.imgur.com/Co5WV.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to disable Gutenberg editor. To achieve this, you can install a plugin which disables it, here are few:

- [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)
- [Disable Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/)

Comment: i mean my contant language is germany and wordpress is germany why in YOAST pluagin give my readability is not good Because he did not understand that the language is German or the words written in German, he thinks they are English